# How do I insert a "close" link in this list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code:

```
// If JS enabled, disable main input
$("#responsibilities").prop('disabled', true);
// $("#responsibilities").addClass("hidden");

// If JS enabled then add fields
$("#resp").append('<input placeholder="Add responsibility" id="resp_input" ></input><input type="button" value="Add" id="add"> ');

// Add items to input field
var eachline='';
$("#add").click(function(){
    var lines = $('#resp_input').val().split('\n');
    var lines2 = $('#responsibilities').val().split('\n');
    if(lines2.length>10)return false;
    for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
        if(lines[i]!='' && i+lines2.length<11){
        eachline += lines[i] + '\n';
        }    
    }

        $('#responsibilities').text($("<div>" + eachline + "</div>").text()).before("<li>"+$("<p>"+lines+"</p>").text()+"</li>");

    $('#resp_input').val('');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZTuDJ/40/

I'm trying to put a "remove" right aligned to each item which comes up in the list when a responsibility is added. This is the code I tried but it stops the javascript from working and seems to be crappy markup anyway. Can anyone point me in the right direction of how this should be done please.

JS

```
$('#responsibilities').text($("<div>" + eachline + "</div>").text()).before("<li>"+$("<p>"+lines+"</p>").text()+"</li><span class="right"><a href="#">Remove</a></span>");
```

CSS

```
.right { float: right; }
```

Comment: `"</li><span class="right"><a href="#">Remove</a></span>");` escape the double quotes or use single quotes, otherwise your code will throw an exception

Comment: The SO syntax highlighter even clued you in to what was wrong (not escaping your quotes). `$('#responsibilities').text($("<div>" + eachline + "</div>").text()).before("<li>"+$("<p>"+lines+"</p>").text()+"<span class=\"right\"><a href=\"#\">Remove</a></span></li>");`

Comment: Do you have multiple accounts? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178931/jquery-improvement-of-this-script-adding-and-removing-items-from-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is messed up due to `"` in `<span class="right"><a href="#">Remove</a></span>`

As, you can't add other elements in UL except LI, you can add your `remove` inside of li

```
$('#responsibilities').text($("<div>" + eachline + "</div>").text())
.before("<li>"+$("<p>"+lines+"</p>")
.text()+" : <span class='right'><a href='#'>Remove</a></span></li>");
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/ZTuDJ/42/

Answer (score 1):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/ZTuDJ/45/) might help you!

**JS**

```
$('#responsibilities').text($("<div>" + eachline + "</div>").text()).before("<li>"+$("<p>"+lines+"</p>").text()+" : <span class='right'><a href='#'>Remove</a></span></li>");
```

**CSS**

```
.right {
    float: right;
}
```